# Selenium Excel VBA to open tabs for use by instances of a Class

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

First interaction. Hello everyone.

I have had an application running in Excel VBA for a few years. It has worked well for me in maintaining a non-profits database. However, to take advantage of the built in features, I interacted with Internet Explorer. The database administrators have made modifications that are not supported by the end of life IE, so my Macro Code no longer works.

In IE, at a module level in VBA, I instantiated a browser object, logged in, and filtered for the base url of profiles I needed to update.

I then create up to 30 instances of "Profile" Class objects, each then instantiated it's own browser object. The primary reason for the parallelism was to allow the interactions with the Server to happen in the background, with my interactions grouped in time. I start it, go away for 2 minutes, make 30 decisions in 45 to 60 seconds, go away for 6 minutes, loop...

The module level code loops through the 30 Profiles advancing them through their internal States. If a Profile is waiting for a page to load, it skips it's time and doesn't hold up the others.

The "Profile" Class is structured as a State Machine that sequentially steps through a passed base url and other sub-urls for that profile and extracts information. It then modifies it (if needed, determined by user), saves the new information reports done and awaits another base url. Instantiating a separate IE browser object for each individual profile still used the original Login data, so was simple, but used memory. However, trying the same thing with Selenium and Chrome. The separate instantiations each require a login.

But using Selenium and Chrome, each instantiated browser need new login information, so I would like to create a new tab and pass that to each "Profile" so all of it's interactions would be contained in that tab. (Avoiding the possibility of profiles stepping on each other...)

If I have a Selenium Chrome 'driver' created, I can create a new tab by "driver.SendKeys Keys.Control, "t".

Questions:

1. How do I pass this specific 'tab' to an instantiation of a Class so that object always uses that tab?
2. How do I know which 'tab' was just created? Just using "driver.SwitchToNextWindow" doesn't guarantee it is the one just created.

Sorry so long. This just happened and I am trying for a solution so I can do the updates this weekend...

Comment: 1) You can pass the handle and switch the driver to use that handle.  The handles are unique ids for the window/tab.  Remember though that one driver = one browser... though there are some hacky ways to use the same session with multiple drivers... 2) Compare driver.getCurrentWindowHandle (returns driver's current handle), with driver.getWindowHandles (returns set of browser's window handles).  The handle that is not the current driver is the one you just opened.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am not familiar with this, I downloaded Selenium wrapper and the appropriate chromedriver for my version. However, the Selenium wrapper does not expose the getCurrentWindowHandle or getWindowsHandles methods to Excel VBA. I am looking at VBS WebDriver, but some reviews are not flattering.

Comment: Does `driver.Window.Title` achieve what you're after?